# unable to use barba js with cdn link

Tags: javascript, html, css, gsap, barbajs

oss-Origin Read Blocking (CORB) blocked cross-origin response https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@barba/core@2.9.7/dist/barba.umd.js.map with MIME type application/json. See https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5629709824032768 for more details.

i am getting the above following error
firstly i used https://unpkg.com/@barba/core.
which was also giving error but another now i am using

https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@barba/core@2.9.7/dist/barba.umd.js.map

this is giving error mentioned above. Please help

i was expecting page transistions with barba js but giving error

Comment: Are you trying to get the .map file in a script tag? The javascript file [https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@barba/core@2.9.7/dist/barba.umd.js](https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@barba/core@2.9.7/dist/barba.umd.js) works fine